# vscode commenting (Ctrl + /) in typescript not working

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I have installed the latest version of vscode. But apparently it couldn't auto detect any typescript files. I fixed with it by  configuring the ts file association to **typescript**. This worked.

However, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> was not working. It works fine with other languages but not typescript. I tried everything but none worked. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the [TypeScript Extension Pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=loiane.ts-extension-pack) if you haven't done yet.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> .

Comment: Please [edit] to explain the effect of your proposal and why it helps to solve the problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).